# How to delete specific commas and doublequotations from textfile

Tags: excel, csv, replace, export-to-csv, vba

I am exporting a sheet as a CSV from Excel, but I am getting this line in the beginning of the CSV file:
`"UTF-8","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""`
So how do I get rid of this? I have tried CurrRow.Replace, etc. I can get it to replace words and whatnot, but not this line or any commas or double quotations.
Some help would really be appreciated.

```
  Set UTFStream = CreateObject("adodb.stream")
  UTFStream.Type = adTypeText
  UTFStream.Mode = adModeReadWrite
  UTFStream.Charset = "UTF-8"
  UTFStream.LineSeparator = adLF
  UTFStream.Open

  'set field separator
  ListSep = ","
  'set source range with data for csv file
  If Selection.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    Set SrcRange = Selection
  Else
    Set SrcRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  End If

  For Each CurrRow In SrcRange.Rows
    'enclose each value with quotation marks and escape quotation marks in values
    CurrTextStr = ""
    For Each CurrCell In CurrRow.Cells
      CurrTextStr = CurrTextStr & """" & CurrCell.Value & """" & ListSep
    Next

    'remove ListSep after the last value in line
    While Right(CurrTextStr, 1) = ListSep
      CurrTextStr = Left(CurrTextStr, Len(CurrTextStr) - 1)

      'CurrRow.Replace What:=Chr(44) & "UTF-8" & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(44), Replacement:="X"

    Wend
    'add line to UTFStream
    UTFStream.WriteText CurrTextStr, adWriteLine
  Next
```

Comment: have you tried saving the range/content to a new file and saving that file as a csv?

Comment: Hello, I have done the following (as you can see below). So I add it as a text file and then save it as the existing csv. However, I have some issues with the loop I am doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this solved my issue. However, it works fine without the `version check`. I cannot get it to work with it, tried to debug it, but it seems like the path is correct?

```
Sub RemoveCommasDoubleQ()

'    Enable a reference to 'Microsft Scripting Runtime'
'    under VBA menu option Tools > References

Dim week, UserName As String
Dim MyFile, MyFilePath As String
Dim version As Integer

' Current week, XX
week = Format(Date, "ww")
' Username, e.g. niclas.madsen
UserName = Environ$("UserName")
' Initials, first letter of last and surname to caps
' e.g. niclas.madsen would be NM
UserName = UCase(Left(UserName, 1) & Mid(UserName, InStr(UserName, ".") + 1, 1))

' fix filename for saving purpose
MyFile = Replace(Replace("SupplierOrganization_W", "", ""), ".", "_") _
        & "" _
        & week _
        & " " _
        & UserName _
        & ".csv"
'SupplierOrganization_WXX NM

MyFilePath = getDirSubParentPath & MyFile

' Version check
Do While Len(Dir(MyFilePath)) <> 0
version = version + 1
MyFilePath = getDirSubParentPath & "SupplierOrganization_W" & week & "-" & version & " " & UserName & ".csv"
Loop

'Const tmpFile As String = "C:\Users\niclas.madsen\Desktop\AP\tmp_file.txt"

Dim tmpFile, tmpFilePath As String
tmpFile = getDirSubParentPath & "tmp_file.txt"


Dim tmpString As String
'Dim fso As New FileSystemObject


Dim fso As Object 'scripting.filesystemobject
Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

If fso.FileExists(MyFilePath) = True Then
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Open MyFilePath For Input As #1
Open tmpFile For Output As #2
tmpString = Input(LOF(1), 1) 'read the entire file
tmpString = Replace(tmpString, (Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) _
& Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) _
& Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) _
& Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) _
& Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) _
& Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) _
& Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) _
& Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) _
& Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) _
& Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) _
& Chr(34)), "") 'eliminate double quotation and commas in the first line with UTF-8
Print #2, tmpString 'output result
Close #1
Close #2
fso.DeleteFile (MyFilePath) 'delete original file
fso.CopyFile tmpFile, MyFilePath, True 'rename temp file
fso.DeleteFile (tmpFile) 'delete temp file
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Finished processing file", vbInformation, "Done!"
Else
MsgBox "Cannot locate the file : " & MyFile, vbCritical, "Error"
End If
Set fso = Nothing
End Sub

' Get Parent Sub Directory Path
Function getDirSubParentPath()
getDirSubParentPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "CSV" & Application.PathSeparator & "Parent" & Application.PathSeparator
End Function
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29635147/how-to-add-an-incremental-count-version-to-a-string-file-in-excel-vba