# How to add an incremental count (version) to a string (file) in Excel/VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, while-loop, count

I have tried a lot of different things, and it seems like I cannot get it to work. So basically, this is a small piece of my complete code.
I am using `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` to save the file, using the FileExists() to check if the file actually exist before saving.
This is working fine if I remove the IF-statement/Loop.
However, now it feels like `FileExists` won´t find the string, `MyFilePath`, when I run it with the IF/Loop. (getdirsubparentpath is a function)

```
Dim week, UserName As String
Dim MyFile, MyFilePath As String
Dim version As Integer


' Current week, XX
week = Format(Date, "ww")
' Username, e.g. niclas.madsen
UserName = Environ$("UserName")
' Initials, first letter of last and surname to caps
' e.g. niclas.madsen would be NM
UserName = UCase(Left(UserName, 1) & Mid(UserName, InStr(UserName, ".") + 1, 1))

' fix filename for saving purpose
MyFile = Replace(Replace("SupplierOrganization_W", "", ""), ".", "_") _
        & "" _
        & week _
        & " " _
        & UserName _
        & ".csv"
'SupplierOrganization_WXX NM

MyFilePath = getDirSubParentPath & MyFile

' Look for the MyFilePath, if it exists then
' Add "-1" after the week number, if 1 exists, add 2, etc.
If Len(Dir(MyFilePath)) <> 0 Then
version = 0
Do
version = version + 1
MyFilePath = Dir(getDirSubParentPath & "SupplierOrganization_W" & week & "-" & version & " " & UserName & ".csv")
Loop Until Len(Dir(MyFilePath)) < 0
End If

Dim tmpFile, tmpFilePath As String
tmpFile = getDirSubParentPath & "tmp_file.txt"


Dim tmpString As String
'Dim fso As New FileSystemObject


Dim fso As Object 'scripting.filesystemobject
Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

If fso.FileExists(MyFilePath) = True Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Open MyFilePath For Input As #1
    Open tmpFile For Output As #2
    tmpString = Input(LOF(1), 1) 'read the entire file
    tmpString = Replace(tmpString, (Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) _
    & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) _
    & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) _
    & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) _
    & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) _
    & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) _
    & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) _
    & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) _
    & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) _
    & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) _
    & Chr(34)), "") 'eliminate double quotation and commas in the first line with UTF-8
    Print #2, tmpString 'output result
    Close #1
    Close #2
    fso.DeleteFile (MyFilePath) 'delete original file
    fso.CopyFile tmpFile, MyFilePath, True 'rename temp file
    fso.DeleteFile (tmpFile) 'delete temp file
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Finished processing file", vbInformation, "Done!"
Else
    MsgBox "Cannot locate the file : " & MyFilePath, vbCritical, "Error"
End If
Set fso = Nothing
End Sub




' Get Parent Sub Directory Path
Function getDirSubParentPath()
getDirSubParentPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "CSV" & Application.PathSeparator & "Parent" & Application.PathSeparator
End Function
```

Comment: Can you update your question to give an example of the string that gets returned from the `getDirSubParentPath()` method please.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don´t have access to it right now (it is on my workstation). But I have updated it with something similar to what I use.

Comment: OK, the point I was getting at anyway - was to make sure that the string being returned ends with a "\" so that it's a valid file path for the `Dir()` function.

Comment: Updated the function to the one I use.

Comment: Also, you're not using the `.FileExists()` method anywhere? You're using `Len(Dir())` which is a different thing altogether.

Comment: It is in the rest of the code.. I can update it if you want :)

Comment: If you replace those `Len(Dir())` statements with the `.FileExists()` method - you will probably solve your own problem ;)

Comment: @SOofWXLS I have tried another loop that works when I am saving the files (in another sub). However, in this sub it doesn´t work. `FileExists(MyFilePath)` is apparently "False" when I use that loop (it jumps to the Else-statement), however, it can return the correct name of the file in `MsgBox`. I am pretty lost, think I tried the most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally manage to create a solution that seems viable. However, the code could use some cleaning up :) But it gets the job done.
So basically, I am having some issues with the loop. It will return a file named W16-0 (which should actual just be W16). It should only add the "-X" if W16 is found. So the incremental order should be W16, W16-1, W16-2, etc.
What I am doing is that I try to locate if there is a W16-0 and then replace it with W16. Furthermore, it seems like the loop will give me one higher than the amount of files I have. So that is where I also got an error. So if I had a W16-4, it would ask the macro to find and open a file named W16-5, which would obviously not exist.
If somebody could help me clean up the code, I would be really thankful!

```
Sub RemoveCommasDoubleQ()
'
'    Enable a reference to 'Microsft Scripting Runtime'
'    under VBA menu option Tools > References

Dim week, UserName As String
Dim MyFile, MyFilePath As String
Dim version As Integer

Dim fso As Object 'scripting.filesystemobject
Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

' Current week, XX
week = Format(Date, "ww")
' Username, e.g. niclas.madsen
UserName = Environ$("UserName")
' Initials, first letter of last and surname to caps
' e.g. niclas.madsen would be NM
UserName = UCase(Left(UserName, 1) & Mid(UserName, InStr(UserName, ".") + 1, 1))

' fix filename for saving purpose
MyFile = Replace(Replace("SupplierOrganization_W", "", ""), ".", "_") _
            & "" _
            & week _
            & " " _
            & UserName _
            & ".csv"
    'SupplierOrganization_WXX NM

'MyFilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\CSV\Parent\" & MyFile
MyFilePath = getDirSubParentPath & MyFile

Debug.Print MyFilePath
Debug.Print "BEFORE LOOP"
'version = 1

Do While Len(Dir(MyFilePath)) <> 0
     '// If it does, then append a _000 to the name
     '// Change _000 to suit your requirement
    MyFilePath = getDirSubParentPath & "SupplierOrganization_W" & week & "-" & version & " " & UserName & ".csv"

     '// Increment the counter
    version = version + 1

     '// and go around again

    If MyFilePath = getDirSubParentPath & "SupplierOrganization_W" & week & "-0" & " " & UserName & ".csv" Then
       MyFilePath = getDirSubParentPath & "SupplierOrganization_W" & week & " " & UserName & ".csv"
       Debug.Print MyFilePath
       Debug.Print "IF LOOP"
    End If
Loop
Debug.Print MyFilePath
Debug.Print "LOOP"

If fso.FileExists(getDirSubParentPath & "SupplierOrganization_W" & week & "-" & version & " " & UserName & ".csv") = False Then
    MyFilePath = getDirSubParentPath & "SupplierOrganization_W" & week & "-" & version - 2 & " " & UserName & ".csv"
    MsgBox getDirSubParentPath & "SupplierOrganization_W" & week & "-" & version & " " & UserName & ".csv"
End If

fileName = fso.GetFileName(MyFilePath)
Debug.Print fileName

If MyFilePath = getDirSubParentPath & "SupplierOrganization_W" & week & "-0" & " " & UserName & ".csv" Then
   MyFilePath = getDirSubParentPath & "SupplierOrganization_W" & week & " " & UserName & ".csv"
   Debug.Print MyFilePath
   Debug.Print "her it should be 0"
End If

If MyFilePath = getDirSubParentPath & "SupplierOrganization_W" & week & "-" & " " & UserName & ".csv" Then
   MyFilePath = getDirSubParentPath & "SupplierOrganization_W" & week & "-" & version & " " & UserName & ".csv"
End If



Debug.Print "HER ER VI"
fileName = fso.GetFileName(MyFilePath)
Debug.Print fileName


Dim tmpFile, tmpFilePath As String
tmpFile = getDirSubParentPath & "tmp_file.txt"

Dim tmpString As String

Debug.Print "------"
Debug.Print MyFilePath

If fso.FileExists(getDirSubParentPath & "SupplierOrganization_W" & week & "-0" & " " & UserName & ".csv") = True Then
   MsgBox "Found the W-0"
   MyFilePath = getDirSubParentPath & "SupplierOrganization_W" & week & " " & UserName & ".csv"
End If

Debug.Print "Found 0?"
Debug.Print MyFilePath


If fso.FileExists(MyFilePath) = True Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Open MyFilePath For Input As #1
    Open tmpFile For Output As #2
    tmpString = Input(LOF(1), 1) 'read the entire file
    tmpString = Replace(tmpString, (Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) _
    & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) _
    & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) _
    & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) _
    & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) _
    & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) _
    & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) _
    & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) _
    & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) _
    & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) _
    & Chr(34)), "") 'eliminate double quotation and commas in the first line with UTF-8
    Print #2, tmpString 'output result
    Close #1
    Close #2
    fso.DeleteFile (MyFilePath) 'delete original file
    fso.CopyFile tmpFile, MyFilePath, True 'rename temp file
    fso.DeleteFile (tmpFile) 'delete temp file
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Finished processing file", vbInformation, "Done!"
Else
    MsgBox "Cannot locate the file : " & MyFile, vbCritical, "Error"
End If
Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```